# Energy of a compressible viscous fluid

Tags: fluid-dynamics, flow, viscosity, navier-stokes

I'm trying to derive an expression for the total energy of a compressible viscous fluid. I know that the energy per unit volume of a compressible inviscid fluid is given by the sum of its kinetic energy and internal energy:
$$E = \frac{1}{2} \rho v^2 + \frac{P}{\gamma-1}$$

where $\rho$ is the fluid density, $v$ is the fluid velocity, $P$ is the pressure, and $\gamma$ is the ideal gas adiabatic index parameter.

I'm struggling to derive a similar expression for a viscous fluid. In particular I'm not sure if there should be be a contribution to the energy as a result of viscosity, such that we would get an equation of the following form?

$$E = \frac{1}{2} \rho v^2 + \frac{P}{\gamma-1} + E_{viscous}$$

In the literature I have mostly only found the energy of viscous **incompressible** fluids discussed. In Landau & Lifschitz *Fluid Mechanics* Chapter 2, section 16, an expression for the energy dissipation of a viscous incompressible fluid is derived, which describes the decrease per unit time of kinetic energy due to dissipation into heat.

I could follow a similar derivation for a compressible fluid, but my intuition is that if I'm interested in the total energy of the fluid, I don't need to consider dissipation. Any dissipation of mechanical energy into heat will be equivalent to a conversion of kinetic energy into internal energy. That is, an increase in heat in the system will result in an equal increase in internal energy. Adding viscosity to our model doesn't add a source of energy, but rather a mechanism by which mechanical energy can be converted into heat energy through friction. If that is the case, does the contribution of viscosity to the total energy need to be explicitly stated? Or is my intuition way off here?

I would also be grateful if you could point me to any literature that discusses the energy of viscous compressible fluids.

Comment: Did you read Landau & Lifshitz section 49? Also, Lagerstrom's Laminar flow theory